# get maximum value from foreach object list swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I get a maximum value from my object with a let?

```
var body: some View{
    ZStack{
           ForEach(schoolClasses, id: \.self) { studentList in
  
                 let oldestStudent = studentList.max { $0.age < $1.age } //this does not work, trying to return the oldest student
           
                 HStack{
                  //extra code to use the oldest student          
                 }
          }
       }
   }
```

How I can use that let value inside the HStack?

Right now it gives me build error: *`The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`*

Comment: Assuming `studentList` is a array of `[Student]`, then try this approach:
 `let oldestStudent = studentList.students.max { $0.age < $1.age }`. If not, show what `studentList` is made of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, as shown in this example code, to obtain and use the
oldest student in a list of `Student`:

```
struct StudentList: Hashable {
    var students = [ Student(age: 5), Student(age: 6), Student(age: 8), Student(age: 3)]
    //...
}

struct Student: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var age: Int
    //... name etc...
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var schoolClasses = [StudentList()]
    
    var body: some View{
        ForEach(schoolClasses, id: \.self) { studentList in
            if let oldestStudent = studentList.students.max(by: { $0.age < $1.age }) {
                HStack{
                    // Text(oldestStudent.name)
                    Text("oldest student age: \(oldestStudent.age)")
                }
            } else {
                Text("no oldest student available")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if you have a solution for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75561419/transition-on-button-without-toggle-or-withanimation-swiftui

Answer (score 1):

Your code implies that `schoolClasses` is a nested array `[[SchoolClass]]`
which makes no sense.

A reasonable data structure is an array of students in each class

```
struct Student {
    let age: Int
}

struct SchoolClass: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var students : [Student]
}
```

In SwiftUI it's good practice to keep as much computing stuff as possible out of the view.

Add a computed property to `SchoolClass`

```
struct SchoolClass: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var students : [Student]

    var oldestStudent : Student? {
        if students.isEmpty { return nil }
        return students.max { $0.age < $1.age }
    }
}
```

In the view write

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        ForEach(schoolClasses) { schoolClass in
            if let oldestStudent = schoolClass.oldestStudent {
           
                 HStack {
                     //extra code to use the oldest student 
                 }         
             }
         }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I was wondering if you have a solution for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75561419/transition-on-button-without-toggle-or-withanimation-swiftui